# how to identify the image take from uiimagePicketController is screenshot or camera image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
NSLog(@"done");

headingLabel.hidden= NO;
//[self playMovie];
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self setupCroppingTool:selectedImage];
```

}

this is the code,so how can i identify the selectedImage is screenshot or camera image

Comment: hi..where you want to check..you are comparing two external image or internal image

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo
```

This method picks the `image` from **photo library**. You cant compare a `screenshot image` with a `normal image` because both are `UIImage`.

Comment: ohh thats really problem for me :(

Comment: Can you tell me what you exactly want ... your question is strange and i dont think this would be a problem.

Comment: the problem is my cropping code works gud for camera image not for screenshot image and my other code works well for screenshot image too but it does not maintain the aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

May be help..

I think source property of `UIImagePickerController` help you.

Example.

```
UIImagePickerController *abc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];;
abc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

You can use one of this..

```
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
```

Comment: sorry I clicked wrong. I wanted to UPVOTE this :D but now I cant

Answer (score 0):

Look at the image metadata - date, keywords, geolocation... and compare that.